# JHipster tests throw java.lang.OutOfMemoryError in main

Tags: java, spring-boot, permgen, jhipster

I have a project generated with JHipster. When I run the tests I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
```

The tests are configured like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MyApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest
public class MyControllerTest {
   // some CRUD tests (create, update, put and delete)
}
```

From what I can tell spring boot starts an embedded tomcat to run the CRUD tests. How can I extend the permgen space and heap memory for these tests? Should I set some property in the application-dev.yml file?

Thank you,
Tekin.

Comment: I found that @IntegrationTest starts the embedded Tomcat. Is there a way to send -Xms512m -Xmx512m to it or use a standalone tomcat?

Comment: Have you tried setting a JAVA_OPTS environment variable?